# IBM i QtmhCvtDB alternative to be called out of HTTP server

Tags: http, ibm-midrange, cobol

I need to transform POST data to a recordset in an IBM i system. For this purpose I'm using API QtmhCvtDB.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaie/rzaieapi_qtmhcvtdb.htm

But I'm doing it out of CGI stack, I'm doing it implementing command bus pattern, then I get:

Response code -5
This API is not valid when a program is not called by HTTP Server. No data parsing is done.

Is there something like QtmhCvtDB but executable from whole system?

Comment: Where are you getting the POST data?

Comment: A CGI receive POST data and send a message to something like an Enterprise Service Bus where workers like daemons jobs process messages. I want to execute QtmhCvtDB out of CGI to avoid to open/close access path for every request.

Comment: Are you sure QtmhCvtDB opens and closes an access path rather than just retrieving the format? Might this be a case of premature optimization? It is my understanding that ESB uses something like XML to pass messages around Maybe you could use JSON, but I believe you are either goung to have to write something that parses the post data, or use QtmhCvtDB in the CGI program to convert the POST data to something more compatible with ESB.